# Perl - How to crawl a directory, parse every file in the directory and extract all comments to html file

Tags: perl

I need some serious help, I'm new to perl and need help on how to create a perl script that would prompt the user for a directory containing perl files, parse every file in that directory and then extract all comments from each file to individual html files.

code examples or existing modules that already does this would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Are all the files that you wish to extract comments from, are they all the same type?  The people answering this need to know because perl, C++, and html all have different character sequences to indicate comments.  Also, are you wanting HTML output? What do you want that html to look like (a table, a list, organized by file, etc..)?

Answer (score 2):

[PPI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PPI) can be used to parse Perl code files.  This should get you started on getting Perl files in a directory (assuming they have `.pl` extensions) and grabbing the comments. I'm not sure what you mean about the HTML piece:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use PPI;

my $dir = shift;
for my $file (glob "$dir/*.pl") {
    my $doc = PPI::Document->new($file);
    for my $com (@{ $doc->find('PPI::Token::Comment') }) {
        print $com->{content};
    }
}
```

Update:  Look at [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aTemplate) (but it may be overkill).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. On the html piece, I want all my comments to be written to html files for documentation purposes without using POD.

Answer (score 0):

A simple cpan search with keyword "dir" turned up a whole slew of helpful modules.  One of the ones I use a lot is:

[IO::Dir](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Dir.pm)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a choice, here's a Ruby script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 
print "Enter directory: "
directory=File.join(gets.chomp,"*.pl")
directory="/home/yhlee/test/ruby/*.pl"
c=0
Dir[directory].each do |file|
    c+=1
    o = File.open("file_#{c}.html","w")
    File.open(file).each do |line|
        if line[/#/]
            o.write ( line.scan(/;*\s+(#.*)$/)[0].first + "\n" ) if line[/;*\s+#/]
            o.write ( line.scan(/^\s+(#.*)$/)[0].first + "\n") if line[/^\s+#/]
        end
    end
    o.close
end
```

Comment: What does that do for a line of Perl code like "while (1) { # a comment" ?  (my guess is it does the Wrong Thing...)